# Unable to find c:\windows\system32\mfc100d.dll

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have a very strange problem.

I am trying to run a console application that I build using VS2010 and get the error `mfc100d.dll` not found. However this dll is present in `c:\windows\system32` and my path is `c:\windows\system32`

If I copy the file from `c:\windows\system32` to my current directory it works.

If I add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.DebugMFC\` to my path, it also works.

It was all working fine until I uninstalled a program yesterday and installed new version of it. But the thing I just can't understand is why I am getting errors when the `mfc100d.dll` is really there in the `C:\windows\system32` path.

And, yes, I do have the rights to read the file, how else can I copy it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a 32-bit application running on 64-bit Windows, accessing the `System32` directory gets redirected to the `SysWOW64` directory. Take this output from 32-bit Python, for example:

```
>>> import os
>>> print(os.path._getfinalpathname(r'C:\Windows\System32\mfc100d.dll'))
\\?\C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mfc100d.dll
```

Keep in mind that both filesystem and registry paths can get redirected due to WOW64 and UAC, so you don't always get *exactly* what you asked for! This can catch you off guard if for some reason you end up running a 32-bit command prompt via `SysWOW64\cmd.exe`, especially if you end up running a mixture of 32-bit and 64-bit applications in the same console window.

Comment: Thanks, it was really puzzling to have the path set and the dll not found.. I didn't know about the different behavior for 32 bit dll's on a 64 bit system.

Answer (score 0):

If you uninstalled something maybe your environment variable was reset. Did you check on that?

Comment: My path is set and contains `C:\Windows\System32`. Which other variable could be related to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your `PATH`, see if there are several mfc100d.dll exist in the search path and one of them get broken. (possibly due to the uninstallation)

Comment: I have set the path to `C:\Windows\System32`, mfc100d.dll is present in that folder. However, I still get the error. The file is the same as in the Visual Studio folder, I compared using `FC /b`

Comment: @uncletall Try use `icacls /reset` to reset file permission. Also, check you didn't spell the path wrong. Then reboot and ensure your setting is actually taking place (e.g. use the cmd command `path` and check its output)

Answer (score 0):

Check where that console application is trying to fetch that mfc100d.dll file using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) . Then place mfc100d.dll to the path where it is trying to fetch it.